# Where i can read complete manual to configure SMTP for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, smtp, actionmailer, exim4

I newbie in Rails, and i have some question.
I setup simple application with Devise plugin, deploy it on production server (Ubuntu on Linode, nginx + passenger) via Capistrano. And now try to send emails (password recovery, email confirmation and etc from Devise).

But it doesent work.

I have this lines in /enviroments/production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "myhostname.com" }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

And when i try to send email from my app, i get 500 error "We're sorry, but something went wrong.
" (by Passenger).
In log/production.log

```
Net::SMTPServerBusy (451 4.3.0 Temporary system failure. Please try again later.)
```

I use exim4 as mail server. Also i try install sendmail and change

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

Emails start sends but application work so slow.

So, my question is: what i need to do with my problem and where i can read complete manual or documentation to configure exim4 for work with rails application?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the exim4 works by itself? i.e. without the Rails app? Try to use it with a regular e-mail client (like Thunderbird) and see if it works.

Comment: Yep, exim works. I try -- echo "This is a test." | mail -s Testing someone@somedomain.com. Actualy i dont remember what exactly i do, but problem already solved. I think i just restart ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

According to chapters 5 and 5.1 of ActionMailer official doc : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

We can see that there are no ':exim4' option available as 'delivery_method'.

So I would suggest to "cheat" ActionMailer that he is using sendmail (though he will use exim4).
Use the following configuration in your config/enviroments/production.rb file :

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
  :location => '/usr/sbin/exim4',
  :arguments => '-i'
}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Arguments match the following exim4 options :

- **-t option** causes the recipients of the message to be obtained from the To:, Cc:, and Bcc: header lines in the message instead of
  from the command arguments.
- **-i option** prevents a line containing just a dot from terminating the message. Only an end-of-file does so.

Don't use the -t option.

In order to configure properly your Exim4 deamon, I suggest this quick how-to : http://noosfero.org/Development/MailSending

I highly recommend you choose "**smarthost**" on the first screen instead of "Internet site".

This is because mail providers of the Internet (gmail, yahoo, etc...) do block any e-mails that come from an unkown IP adresses on Internet by default (this include your new server IP adress of course).

If you choose 'smarthost' your server will have to connect to an existing (and trusted) mail server (gmail, yahoo, etc...) in order to forward its own e-mail messages.
This will ensure your e-mails get their ways up to their destination.

=== UPDATE

I had problem making it working with -t optin since some version of rails (3.2).
I had the following error in my **/var/www/my_app/log/production.log** :

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25)
```

So I removed the -t option as rails was not including anymore the To: field in the message and rather sent it in the command line.

I found some other developper having a similar issue on this app : [gitlabhq](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4866)

I hope this help people to make rails working with exim4.

Answer (score 0):

Debian 8 + Rails4.2.6 + Exim version 4.84_2

I added to my *config/enviroments/production.rb* file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_options     = { from: 'mybox@hostname.com' }
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'hostname.com' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries    = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

and clear(commented) from *delivery_method* and *sendmail_settings* params:

```
# config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
# config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
#     :location => '/usr/sbin/exim4',
#     :arguments => '-i'
# }
```

And it's work!

*For me Douglas answer didn't work.*