# How to configure SMTP for exim in linux for Rails4 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, exim

We have Rails4 application. We want to use SMTP via exim.

How to configure SMTP for exim in linux for Rails4 application?

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :exim
```

will this work?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12815481/959041

Answer (score 0):

Debian 8 + Rails4.2.6 + Exim version 4.84_2

I added to my *config/enviroments/production.rb* file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_options     = { from: 'mybox@hostname.com' }
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'hostname.com' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries    = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

and clear(commented) from *delivery_method* and *sendmail_settings* params:

```
# config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
# config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
#     :location => '/usr/sbin/exim4',
#     :arguments => '-i'
# }
```

And it's work!